# How can I send aac raw data via RTP over UDP?

Tags: java, networking, audio, rtp, aac

I have flv files that contain audio tags with a aac raw data. Each audio tag has one array of the aac raw data. Raw data have different sizes. I want send it via RTP. I add 13-bits size AU header. It is first bits of the 2 bytes. Last 3 bits is zero.

audioSpecificConfig is 12 08. 0001 0 010 - AAL LC. 
My SDP are:

```
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 mpeg4-generic/44100/2
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=16; mode=AAC-hbr;
config=1208; sizeLength=13; indexLength=3;
indexDeltaLength=3;
```

I send RTP packets with audio payload grouping RTP packets with video payload. Player play video and don't play audio. 
Where is a problem? Is not valid audio payload header? 
A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: [RFC 3640 for AAC](http://thompsonng.blogspot.com/2010/03/rfc-3640-for-aac.html).
My audio is a pure raw data without ADTS or ADIF headers.